# Getting non-generic type while creating xamarin native bindings

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

I'm trying to create C# Bindings for Native iOS Library, and i've used objective sharpie as a tool to do it, but i'm stuck at one place where it has converted

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<BTPaymentSelectionViewControllerDelegate, BTDropInControllerDelegate, BTAppSwitchDelegate, BTViewControllerPresentingDelegate> delegate;
```

to

```
 [Wrap("WeakDelegate")]
        NSObject<BTPaymentSelectionViewControllerDelegate, BTDropInControllerDelegate, BTAppSwitchDelegate, BTViewControllerPresentingDelegate> Delegate { get; set; }
```

but i'm getting the below error,which makes sense, as i'm fairly new to iOS native Objective C, i'm not sure how to go about this, any inputs would be really helpful

> The non-generic type 'NSObject' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: In native iOS, you can set only one delegate as object

Comment: yes, but then how would i able to get this scenario solved ??

Comment: looks like that `BTPaymentSelectionViewControllerDelegate` and `BTDropInControllerDelegate` have base class from `BTViewControllerPresentingDelegate` am I right?

Comment: It has the following attributes [Protocol, Model]
    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]

Comment: Any help would be really really nice !!